# No module named tkinter

Tags: ros-melodic, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use tkinter in my ROS environment but I am having some trouble getting it set up. I added it to my 'packages.xml' file like this

```
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
<build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
<depend>python-tk</depend>
<build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
<exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
```

but when I install the package with 'rosdep install [my package]', the node I have 'import tkinter' in still will not run, and instead returns 'ImportError: No module named tkinter'. I am relatively new to ROS and have not installed third party packages before so I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Thanks in advance for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353902/no-module-named-tkinter/) by [klastine](https://answers.ros.org/users/55447/klastine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nevermind, I figured it out. I had to use 'import Tkinter' instead of 'import tkinter'.

---

Originally posted by [klastine](https://answers.ros.org/users/55447/klastine/) with karma: 26 on 2020-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1